# Is there an easy way to hook into a DragOver event with this thumb control?

Tags: c#, wpf, events, slider

In this code I have 2 Ellipses, each contained within its own thumb control. In the code-behind, Thumb_DragDelta allows me to freely move the objects around. My questions are: -

1. How can I hook into an event when I drag one over the other (e.g.
   Ellipse1 dragged over Ellipse2). I've tried setting up code in
   DragOver and DragEnter but nothing happens.
2. In the event handler of 1. above, how could I access the properties
   of Ellipse2 to, say, change the fill color?

Here's the xaml: -

```
<Window x:Class="DragDropExample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DragDropExample"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Canvas>
            <Thumb x:Name="Thumb1" Canvas.Left="100" 
                   Canvas.Top="60" 
                   DragDelta="Thumb_DragDelta" 
                   Panel.ZIndex="1">
                <Thumb.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Ellipse x:Name="Ellipse1" 
                                 Fill="#FF6F1D9E" 
                                 Height="85" 
                                 Canvas.Left="379" 
                                 Stroke="Black" 
                                 Canvas.Top="20" 
                                 Width="84" 
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                                 Margin="0,40,36.5,0" 
                                 VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Thumb.Template>
            </Thumb>
            <Thumb x:Name="Thumb2" Canvas.Left="400" 
                   Canvas.Top="60" 
                   DragDelta="Thumb_DragDelta" 
                   Panel.ZIndex="0" 
                   AllowDrop="True">
                <Thumb.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Ellipse x:Name="Ellipse2" 
                                 Fill="#FF9E1D40" 
                                 Height="85" 
                                 Canvas.Left="379" 
                                 Stroke="Black" 
                                 Canvas.Top="20" 
                                 Width="84" 
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                                 Margin="0,40,36.5,0" 
                                 VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Thumb.Template>
            </Thumb>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here's the C# in the code-behind: -

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace DragDropExample
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


private void Thumb_DragDelta(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragDeltaEventArgs e)
        {
            UIElement thumb = e.Source as UIElement;

            Canvas.SetLeft(thumb, Canvas.GetLeft(thumb) + e.HorizontalChange);
            Canvas.SetTop(thumb, Canvas.GetTop(thumb) + e.VerticalChange);
        }
    }
}
```